# Can I call 'Promise.prototype.catch()' in a Jest's test case?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, jestjs

Jest is reporting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFileName' of undefined

      at Function.write (../../../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-util/build/buffered_console.js:33:24)
```

when I do:

```
test('wrap template', () => {
  expect.assertions(1)

  return generate(_cwd)
  .then(done => {
    let builtPageName = path.basename(done.shift())
    expect(builtPageName).toBe('indx.html')
   })
  .catch(console.error)
})
```

But when I remove the `.catch(console.error)`, it's (as usual) pretty-printing this:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected value to be (using ===):
      "indx.html"
    Received:
      "index.html"

      at generate.then.done (lib/__tests__/template.test.js:25:27)
```

Now, this report is what I expect to see from the test tool.

So, **what happens when the test case is run with/without `.catch(...)`?**

I'm running `node 6.11.2`, `npm 5.4.0`, and `jest 21.1.0` at `Windows 7`.

The [full source code for this case](https://github.com/ranieribt/npm-site-gen/tree/getFileName-of-undefined) is also available.